# Terminal command does not work in PhpStorm

Tags: terminal, command, phpstorm

When I try to use the command `java` in the PHPStrom Terminal. I got this error :

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

But I checked I added in PATH the environment variable and it works perfectly on a terminal outside PhpStorm.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the Jetbrains Toolbox to update these commands in terminals.

1. Close PhpStorm
2. Right click on Jetbrains Toolbox and click on "exit"
3. Search jetbrains toolbox in windows to launch again

And all commands work in the Phpstorm terminal.